# How to add some text after the 3rd line of the string match in shell

Tags: unix

I have a xml file. I want to add the line 'a new_text' after the 3rd line of the matching pattern '`<ename>Total Invoices Released</ename>`'. How can i do that using in shell script

INPUT FILE [Form.xml]

```
<Formula>
<ename>Total Invoices Released</ename>
<comment></comment>
<Type>Suspense</Type>
<tags>
<tags>Total Invoice Released</tags>
<tags>Total Invoices Released</tags>
<tags>Total Invoices Released</tags>
```

I used the below code, but it didn't worked

```
sed -n "/<ename>Total Invoices Released</ename>/{N;N;N;a new_text}" Form.xml
```

OUTPUT FILE should look like this

```
<Formula>
<ename>Total Invoices Released</ename>
<comment></comment>
<Type>Suspense</Type>
<tags>
a new_text
<tags>Total Invoice Released</tags>
<tags>Total Invoices Released</tags>
<tags>Total Invoices Released</tags>
```

Answer (score 1):

A program like that:

```
# It stores if the searched text has been matched, or not
matched=false
# The quantity of lines that have been read after the searched text has been matched
linesAfterMatched=0

while IFS= read -r line; do 
    echo "$line"
    if [[ "$matched" == false ]]; then
        if [[ "$line" == "<ename>Total Invoices Released</ename>" ]]; then
            matched=true
        fi
    else
        ((linesAfterMatched += 1))
        if [[ "$linesAfterMatched" == 3 ]]; then
            echo "a new text!"
        fi
    fi
done
```

can be used this way:

```
program.sh < Form.xml
```

and shows:

```
<Formula>
<ename>Total Invoices Released</ename>
<comment></comment>
<Type>Suspense</Type>
<tags>
a new text!
<tags>Total Invoice Released</tags>
<tags>Total Invoices Released</tags>
<tags>Total Invoices Released</tags>
```

And unlike some alternatives that I have been trying with awk or sed, it's very customizable (and more easily).

Comment: Hi This worked. A bit doubt. If i want to search another pattern inside the xml file with the existing pattern and add another pattern after the third line of the serached pattern. How will i do that?

Comment: Hi! This is getting more complex. The standard procedure in StackOverflow is to upvote, and create another question (where you can put a link to the present one).